# Mail - how to show POP3 mail account in the side bar

Tags: macbook-pro, mail.app, pop

This is my Mail screen:

[image]

I have Gmail Imap account and a Bezeqint POP3 account.

I want to see my Bezeqint account in the sidebar as I see Gmail's account so I can add and change folders.

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

POP accounts are view-only and provide no access to folders on the server.  You can create offline folders to keep your POP mail organized on your computer, but obviously these folders will not sync with your online account.